# typo3 : how can i render page's content with fluidpages

Tags: typo3, render, fluid-layout, itemrenderer, fluid

In typo3 6.2, with fluidpage extension. (http://fluidtypo3.org/)

I create a page with 2 fluid content elements.

Im trying to render a page's content with fluid template.
This is my code :

```
<v:content.render column='0' pageUid="3" as="contentElement">
    <f:for each="{contentElement}" as="content">
        <f:debug title="Debug of MyArray">{contentElement}</f:debug>
    </f:for>
</v:content.render>
```

Edit : sry, my mistake i didnt indeent the last line.
About debug, it change nothing, because contentElement is empty.

This displays nothing. When I check array's data, I got empty array.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: first of, the v:content is not closed (maybe just in the snippet), secondly the debug should be on `{content}` in your example, not on `{contentElement}`

Comment: i changed my post, there were some line missing because i didnt indeended it

Comment: Did you set the namespace `{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers} ` on top of the template?

Comment: yes i setted the namespace :
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}